# Angular2 RC6 Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined

Tags: angular, systemjs

I am upgrading my rc5 project to rc6. I have updated the rest of the code, now it compiles, but when I navigate to the project in browser, I am receiving errors.  I think the issue is in my systemjs config file, i.e in System.config

My index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <base href="/">
  <title>Angular2 rc6</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor.css" />

  <script src="node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

  <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
  <script>
    System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <app>Loading...</app>
</body>

</html>
```

systemjs.config.js

```
System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    typescriptOptions: {emitDecoratorMetadata: true},
    map: {
      '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
      'rxjs'    : 'node_modules/rxjs'
    },
    paths: {
      'node_modules/@angular/*': 'node_modules/@angular/*/bundles'
    },
    meta: {
      '@angular/*': {'format': 'cjs'}
    },
    packages: {
      'app'                              : {main: 'main', defaultExtension: 'js'},
      'rxjs'                             : {main: 'Rx'},
      '@angular/core'                    : {main: 'core.umd.min.js'},
      '@angular/common'                  : {main: 'common.umd.min.js'},
      '@angular/compiler'                : {main: 'compiler.umd.min.js'},
      '@angular/platform-browser'        : {main: 'platform-browser.umd.min.js'},
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': {main: 'platform-browser-dynamic.umd.min.js'}
    }
});
```

The project structure is

```
project
|-systemjs.config.js
|-src
    |-index.html
    |-app
       |-main.ts
          |-...
```

Errors

```
typescript.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
shim.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
zone.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
system.src.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
systemjs.config.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
(index):20 Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I believe its because you need to update your Systemjs.config.js file.  Rc.6 made some significant changes to the config file. I solved this error on my own project by copying in the new systemjs.config.js file, making sure if you added special mapping or paths for your project that you add it to the

```
map:{}
```

and

```
paths:{}
```

section on the config.
Also just as a good practice, I would move **index.html** out to the root of your project (next with you systemjs.config.js), and because your **app** folder is nested with a **src** folder, you may need to add it to your map in the systemjs.config for example

```
map{
    app: 'src/app'
}
```

also you can find the new systemjs.config.js here [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)